# Cannot connect to Presto Gateway backend

Tags: presto, trino

Below error occurred when I added a local Trino cluster to local Presto gateway.

```
ERROR [2022-08-18 13:14:26,475] com.lyft.data.gateway.ha.clustermonitor.ActiveClusterMonitor: Error fetching cluster stats from [http://coordinator:8080/ui/api/stats]
! java.net.UnknownHostException: coordinator
! at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
! at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
! at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
! at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
! at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
! at com.lyft.data.gateway.ha.clustermonitor.ActiveClusterMonitor.getPrestoClusterStats(ActiveClusterMonitor.java:94)
! at com.lyft.data.gateway.ha.clustermonitor.ActiveClusterMonitor.lambda$start$0(ActiveClusterMonitor.java:56)
! at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
! at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
! at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here's how I added this backend to Gateway

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8090/entity?entityType=GATEWAY_BACKEND' -d '{"name": "trino-cluster", "proxyTo": "http://coordinator:8080", "active": true, "routingGroup": "adhoc"}'
```

coordinator and workers are running via Docker compose.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can you try removing the port from proxyTo as mentioned here https://github.com/lyft/presto-gateway ?

Comment: still didn't worked after removing port from proxyTo @PrabhakarReddy

Comment: if coordinator and gateway both are running on the same docker container as different images then shouldn't I use http://coordinator:8080 in proxyTo while it is being accessed as localhost:8080 from host machine?

Comment: Yes you can. Here it is unable to identify coordinator as a host